# How to return child as a function in React after modifying the children with React.Children API?

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, children

I do have a component hierarchy like this

```
const Parent = ({ children }) => {
    const modifiedChildren = React.Children(children, (child) => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {...child.props, extraProp: "someValue"})
    })
    return modifiedChildren
}

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Parent>
            <div>First</div>
            <div>Second</div>
            <div>Third</div>
        </Parent>
    )
}
```

It works fine, but I want to return children as a function from `Parent` component.

So my question is how to return children as a function from `Parent`, when you need to manipulate the children first by adding some props, etc

**Edit**

My target is something like this...

```
const Parent = ({ children }) => {
    const data = "some dynamic data"

    // here I want to modify children first, as I need to add some props dynamically
    
    return children(data)
}

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Parent>
            {(data) => (
                <>
                    <div>First</div>
                    <div>Second</div>
                    <div>Third</div>
                </>
            )}
        </Parent>
    )
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `I want to return children as a function from Parent component` ? The parent component must return react elements, it should not return a function

Comment: By `returning children as function` I meant this...

`const Parent = ({ children }) => {
    const data = "some value" // in actual implementation there will be some state for this.

    return children(data)
}`

But how to do this when I need to do some modification on the children first, using React.Children API?

Comment: I don't undestand, you don't need to have a function to use the `data`. You can write `const Parent = ({ children }) => {
    const data = '...';
    return React.Children(children, (child) => {
      // use the data here  
      return React.cloneElement(child, {...child.props, extraProp: "someValue"})
    })
}`

Comment: Thanks @OlivierBoissé for reaching out. You are right, I can do that. Here I have requirements to implement both the pattern.
1. where I am modifying props
2. after modifying props I need to implement child as a function pattern too.

To be more elaborate, I want to add onClick handler on certain element in children. Say I want to add it against <li> element. And onClick, I want to pass a clicked state to the children. In children, I will use that value to conditionally render certain UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your (updated) goals correctly, the following code should work:

```js
const Parent = ({ children }) => {
    const data = "some dynamic data";
    // Call any children specified as functions, passing in data
    let modifiedChildren = children.map((child) =>
      typeof child === 'function' ? child(data) : child);
    // modify modifiedChildren as necessary
    return modifiedChildren;
}
```

Function-specified children are just children.  In your example, `children` will be an array of length 1, with the only item equal to a function. In the code above, I call any function-specified children.  You could instead check whether the array is size 1 and has a single function, and then do something special in that case.